# How to show uniqueness of this complex-valued function,

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a function $f(z)$, that satisfies:

1)$f(z)$ is analytic in the upper half plane, 
$Im(z)>0$, and continuous up to the real axis except at the origin,

2) $f(x)$ is real when x is real and x≠0,
$|f(z)|≤ \large \frac {C}{∣z∣^3}$ when $Im(z)>0$,

3) $f(i)=4i$.
Is this function unique? Why?

My work:

By some trial and error I find that the function $\large f(z)=\frac{4}{z^3}$ works just fine.

This also matches with the solution.

However, the solution that I am comparing my work with claims that this function is unique.  How can I prove the uniqueness?

For instance, something such as $f(z)= \large \frac {-4}{z^5}$ almost works, too, but probably a bit problematic near the origin, and that this function will be bigger than the upper bound of $\large \frac {C}{∣z∣^3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Schwarz reflection to extend your function to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0  \}$. More precisely, let
$$
g(z) = \begin{cases} f(z), & \operatorname{Im}(z) \ge 0 \\ \overline{f(\bar z)}, & \operatorname{Im}(z) < 0. \end{cases}
$$
Since $f$ is real-valued and continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, it's straight-forward to check that $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, and the estimate in 2 holds also on the lower half-plane (and by continuity also on the real axis). Hence $g$ has a pole of order at most $3$ at the origin. In particular,
$$
h(z) = z^3 g(z)
$$
has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$. Thus, by Liouville's theorem $h$ is constant.

Unnesting the above, it follows that $f$ can be written as
$$
f(z) = \frac{C}{z^3}
$$
and $C=4$ from the condition $f(i) = 4i$.

Comment: Hi professor, I am revisiting this problem after taking a few days off.  I have a few follow-up questions, if you don't mind: so, you let f(z) be *some* holomorphic function on the UHP, including $R$, then, by your construction of the function g(z), $\bar f(\bar z)$ is an analytic continuation onto the LHP.  When you say that this is straightforward to check, I am showing it in this manner:  since f(z) is holomorphic on the UHP, it has a convergent power series $\sum c_nz^n$.

Comment: But $\bar f(\bar z)$ is just $\sum \bar c_n z^n$ which has the same convergence properties as the original series, i.e., its absolute convergence is the same as the convergence of $\sum c_nz^n$.  Then for z in the LHP, the convergent power series $\sum \bar c_n z^n$ represents $\bar f(\bar z)$, and so the construction of g(z) is indeed holomorphic on the punctured plane $C \setminus {0}$.  What do you think?  Am I on the right track?  If so, I will proceed with the estimate that you showed and also apply Liouville's theorem, which will give the uniqueness.  Thanks @mrf.

Comment: So, I am really trying to exploit the fact that in complex variables, a function is holomorphic *if and only if* it is represented by a convergent power series (with a positive radius of convergence) -- something that is not guaranteed, regarding analyticity of functions, in the real variables setting.  Please feel free to comment - thanks professor.

Comment: Actually, how can I show the analyticity on the real line (since we can only assume analyticity on the *strict* upper half plane?  I think this would be Morera's theorem, but I was wondering whether you had a neat way of actually proving it simply.  Thanks @mrf.

Comment: Morera's theorem is the key here. You only need to check that $\int_\gamma g(z)\,dz = 0$ for (say) triangles not enclosing the origin. If the triangle cuts the real axis, split it into two curves.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much for your time, professor.  Have a great night, @mrf.